# Can't launch Android emulator

Tags: android, adb, emulation, osx-snow-leopard, bus-error

I'm trying to launch the Android emulator, but it never opens.
I tried to launch the "emulator" executable manually, but I get a bus error.

Every time I try to launch it, I get a new crash log with always the same content.

```
Process:         adb [55871]
Path:            /Applications/Android SDK/sdk/platform-tools/adb
Identifier:      adb
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  eclipse [55840]

Date/Time:       2014-04-03 00:17:37.004 +0200
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)
Report Version:  6

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   ???                             0000000000 0 + 0
1   adb                             0x78148ba3 main + 35
2   adb                             0x78147d55 start + 53

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x782014df  ebx: 0x78148a6e  ecx: 0xbffffab4  edx: 0x00000000
  edi: 0xbffffab4  esi: 0x00000000  ebp: 0xbffffa48  esp: 0xbffff9fc
   ss: 0x0000001f  efl: 0x00010282  eip: 0x00000000   cs: 0x00000017
   ds: 0x0000001f   es: 0x0000001f   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x00000037
  cr2: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
0x78145000 - 0x78243feb +adb ??? (???) <C8FBA3E2-833B-3C42-B262-70592F098272>
 /Applications/Android SDK/sdk/platform-tools/adb
0x8fe00000 - 0x8fe4163b  dyld 132.1 (???) <4CDE4F04-0DD6-224E-ACE5-3C06E169A801> /usr/lib/dyld
0x90131000 - 0x90566ff7  libLAPACK.dylib 219.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <5E2D2283-57DE-9A49-1DB0-CD027FEFA6C2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
0x90691000 - 0x9080cfe7  com.apple.CoreFoundation 6.6.6 (550.44) <F88C95CD-1264-782D-A1F5-204739847E93> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
0x909e0000 - 0x909f1ff7  com.apple.LangAnalysis 1.6.6 (1.6.6) <3036AD83-4F1D-1028-54EE-54165E562650> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LangAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/LangAnalysis
0x90af9000 - 0x90b07fe7  libz.1.dylib 1.2.3 (compatibility 1.0.0) <33C1B260-ED05-945D-FC33-EF56EC791E2E> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x90b08000 - 0x90b4cfe7  com.apple.Metadata 10.6.3 (507.15) <74F05E64-2A68-BA10-CCD4-128D164E5A0F> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
0x90c85000 - 0x90eebff7  com.apple.security 6.1.2 (55002) <E88E133F-5FB3-446F-B753-2B8AD577B46A> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
0x90eec000 - 0x90f29ff7  com.apple.SystemConfiguration 1.10.8 (1.10.2) <50E4D49B-4F61-446F-1C21-1B2BA814713D> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
0x90f2a000 - 0x90f49ff7  com.apple.CoreVideo 1.6.2 (45.6) <EB53CAA4-5EE2-C356-A954-5775F7DDD493> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
0x90f81000 - 0x90f81ff7  com.apple.Accelerate 1.6 (Accelerate 1.6) <3891A689-4F38-FACD-38B2-4BF937DE30CF> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
0x90fea000 - 0x90ff4fe7  com.apple.audio.SoundManager 3.9.3 (3.9.3) <5F494955-7290-2D91-DA94-44B590191771> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonSound.framework/Versions/A/CarbonSound
0x91049000 - 0x9106fffb  com.apple.DictionaryServices 1.1.2 (1.1.2) <43E1D565-6E01-3681-F2E5-72AE4C3A097A> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
0x91070000 - 0x910f2ffb  SecurityFoundation ??? (???) <C4506287-1AE2-5380-675D-95B0291AA425> /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityFoundation.framework/Versions/A/SecurityFoundation
0x910f3000 - 0x910f8ff7  com.apple.OpenDirectory 10.6 (10.6) <0603680A-A002-D294-DE83-0D028C6BE884> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/OpenDirectory
0x910f9000 - 0x91117fe7  libPng.dylib ??? (???) <6C0B95D7-9634-E044-0B79-F1DD56961C33> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib
0x91118000 - 0x91907557  com.apple.CoreGraphics 1.545.0 (???) <1D9DC7A5-228B-42CB-7018-66F42C3A9BB3> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
0x91fa4000 - 0x91fc6fef  com.apple.DirectoryService.Framework 3.6 (621.16) <5566E769-6459-78A7-DD2C-1D3068BD3932> /System/Library/Frameworks/DirectoryService.framework/Versions/A/DirectoryService
0x91fc7000 - 0x92001ff7  libcups.2.dylib 2.8.0 (compatibility 2.0.0) <A6C207E3-7B42-926D-9C93-BE3F50B92496> /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
0x92002000 - 0x92033ff7  libGLImage.dylib ??? (???) <D18E2E76-DBF4-6930-039A-F66CA0D120B3> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLImage.dylib
0x925c2000 - 0x925cdff7  libGL.dylib ??? (???) <3E34468F-E9A7-8EFB-FF66-5204BD5B4E21> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib
0x92712000 - 0x92781ff7  libvMisc.dylib 268.0.1 (compatibility 1.0.0) <595A5539-9F54-63E6-7AAC-C04E1574B050> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
0x92782000 - 0x92884fe7  libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib 0.9.8 (compatibility 0.9.8) <EB34F049-D9E1-BF19-CF03-B26A0352D40C> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
0x92885000 - 0x92932fe7  libobjc.A.dylib 227.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <9F8413A6-736D-37D9-8EB3-7986D4699957> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x92e03000 - 0x92eddfff  com.apple.DesktopServices 1.5.11 (1.5.11) <800F2040-9211-81A7-B438-7712BF51DEE3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DesktopServicesPriv.framework/Versions/A/DesktopServicesPriv
0x92f31000 - 0x92f37fff  com.apple.CommonPanels 1.2.4 (91) <2438AF5D-067B-B9FD-1248-2C9987F360BA> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommonPanels.framework/Versions/A/CommonPanels
0x92fb5000 - 0x92fbcff3  com.apple.print.framework.Print 6.1 (237.1) <F5AAE53D-5530-9004-A9E3-2C1690C5328E> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Print.framework/Versions/A/Print
0x93f12000 - 0x93f1eff7  libkxld.dylib ??? (???) <9A441C48-2D18-E716-5F38-CBEAE6A0BB3E> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x93f76000 - 0x93f7fff7  com.apple.DiskArbitration 2.3 (2.3) <E9C40767-DA6A-6CCB-8B00-2D5706753000> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
0x93f80000 - 0x94012fe7  com.apple.print.framework.PrintCore 6.3 (312.7) <7410D1B2-655D-68DA-D4B9-2C65747B6817> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PrintCore.framework/Versions/A/PrintCore
0x94013000 - 0x94013ff7  com.apple.CoreServices 44 (44) <51CFA89A-33DB-90ED-26A8-67D461718A4A> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
0x94024000 - 0x94031ff7  com.apple.NetFS 3.2.2 (3.2.2) <DDC9C397-C35F-8D7A-BB24-3D1B42FA5FAB> /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFS
0x94073000 - 0x940b9ff7  libauto.dylib ??? (???) <29422A70-87CF-10E2-CE59-FEE1234CFAAE> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
0x94ffe000 - 0x9504efe7  libTIFF.dylib ??? (???) <AB182CEC-188A-F2BC-21E1-0059FD3B2598> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
0x9509d000 - 0x950eafeb  com.apple.DirectoryService.PasswordServerFramework 6.1 (6.1) <00A1A83B-0E7D-D0F4-A643-8C5675C2BB21> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PasswordServer.framework/Versions/A/PasswordServer
0x950eb000 - 0x9512fff3  com.apple.coreui 2 (114) <2234855E-3BED-717F-0BFA-D1A289ECDBDA> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/CoreUI
0x95130000 - 0x951aafff  com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 3.2.6 (3.2.6) <156A532C-0B60-55B0-EE27-D02B82AA6217> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio
0x951ab000 - 0x95516ff7  com.apple.QuartzCore 1.6.3 (227.37) <E323A5CC-499E-CA9E-9BC3-537231449CAA> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore
0x9569d000 - 0x956f0ff7  com.apple.HIServices 1.8.3 (???) <1D3C4587-6318-C339-BD0F-1988F246BE2E> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices
0x95746000 - 0x957e1fe7  com.apple.ApplicationServices.ATS 275.19 (???) <2E83B3E9-AF39-36FC-5D05-CC1E952098AB> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/ATS
0x957e2000 - 0x957e2ff7  com.apple.Carbon 150 (152) <8F767518-AD3C-5CA0-7613-674CD2B509C4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon
0x95b30000 - 0x95cf3feb  com.apple.ImageIO.framework 3.0.6 (3.0.6) <AE641FAD-DF38-AE31-B45B-85AEE7AF3A45> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
0x95ed9000 - 0x95edbff7  com.apple.securityhi 4.0 (36638) <6118C361-61E7-B34E-93DB-1B88108F8F18> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SecurityHI.framework/Versions/A/SecurityHI
0x961df000 - 0x961e2ff7  libCoreVMClient.dylib ??? (???) <37F56237-4ABA-E5B5-968D-70FFE357E8E0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x961e3000 - 0x961e7ff7  libGFXShared.dylib ??? (???) <09540618-2ED1-72C4-61CB-938B35927568> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGFXShared.dylib
0x9621d000 - 0x96245ff7  libxslt.1.dylib 3.24.0 (compatibility 3.0.0) <E761F29A-328B-29D9-3DF0-023F2C21E500> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x9628f000 - 0x962a3ffb  com.apple.speech.synthesis.framework 3.10.35 (3.10.35) <57DD5458-4F24-DA7D-0927-C3321A65D743> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesis
0x963fd000 - 0x96421ff7  libJPEG.dylib ??? (???) <50E17B4D-63D6-24D3-702F-6A6E912A55EA> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib
0x96425000 - 0x964a5feb  com.apple.SearchKit 1.3.0 (1.3.0) <9E18AEA5-F4B4-8BE5-EEA9-818FC4F46FD9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
0x964a8000 - 0x964ebff7  libGLU.dylib ??? (???) <6CC3CE6A-7024-C685-EADA-7F9DC27128E2> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLU.dylib
0x9656d000 - 0x96570fe7  libmathCommon.A.dylib 315.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <1622A54F-1A98-2CBE-B6A4-2122981A500E> /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
0x96571000 - 0x96589ff7  com.apple.CFOpenDirectory 10.6 (10.6) <D1CF5881-0AF7-D164-4156-9E9067B7FA37> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFOpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/CFOpenDirectory
0x9658a000 - 0x96627fe3  com.apple.LaunchServices 362.3 (362.3) <15B47388-16C8-97DA-EEBB-1709E136169E> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
0x9663f000 - 0x96653fe7  libbsm.0.dylib ??? (???) <14CB053A-7C47-96DA-E415-0906BA1B78C9> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x96654000 - 0x96664ff7  libsasl2.2.dylib 3.15.0 (compatibility 3.0.0) <C8744EA3-0AB7-CD03-E639-C4F2B910BE5D> /usr/lib/libsasl2.2.dylib
0x96665000 - 0x9680cff7  libSystem.B.dylib 125.2.11 (compatibility 1.0.0) <2DCD13E3-1BD1-6F25-119A-3863A3848B90> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x9680d000 - 0x96871ffb  com.apple.htmlrendering 72 (1.1.4) <4D451A35-FAB6-1288-71F6-F24A4B6E2371> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HTMLRendering.framework/Versions/A/HTMLRendering
0x96872000 - 0x96972fe7  libxml2.2.dylib 10.3.0 (compatibility 10.0.0) <BE7FCD73-03B5-25A4-FCA4-D4980F1488D6> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x9698c000 - 0x96a38fe7  com.apple.CFNetwork 454.12.4 (454.12.4) <DEDCD006-389F-967F-3405-EDF541F406D7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
0x96a7a000 - 0x96bfcfe7  libicucore.A.dylib 40.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <60FF302E-5FAE-749B-BC70-0496DC2FBF2D> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x96d8c000 - 0x96e44feb  libFontParser.dylib ??? (???) <D2D0C922-5ED1-3AE9-6F99-707C74DF3E62> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontParser.dylib
0x96ebd000 - 0x96f88fef  com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices 359.2 (359.2) <7C16D9C8-6F41-5754-17F7-2659D9DD9579> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
0x96f89000 - 0x96f9bff7  com.apple.MultitouchSupport.framework 207.11 (207.11) <6FF4F2D6-B8CD-AE13-56CB-17437EE5B741> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MultitouchSupport.framework/Versions/A/MultitouchSupport
0x96fbe000 - 0x96fd3fff  com.apple.ImageCapture 6.1 (6.1) <B909459A-EAC9-A7C8-F2A9-CD757CDB59E8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageCapture.framework/Versions/A/ImageCapture
0x97677000 - 0x976b9ff7  libvDSP.dylib 268.0.1 (compatibility 1.0.0) <8A4721DE-25C4-C8AA-EA90-9DA7812E3EBA> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
0x976ba000 - 0x976baff7  com.apple.ApplicationServices 38 (38) <8012B504-3D83-BFBB-DA65-065E061CFE03> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
0x97bb7000 - 0x97cf4fe7  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox 1.6.7 (1.6.7) <423BDE4D-5082-B6CA-BB2C-E22A037235A4> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
0x98649000 - 0x986aafe7  com.apple.CoreText 151.13 (???) <23F359DA-D845-5C50-4DF3-19E858CF2B2C> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
0x98733000 - 0x98776ff7  com.apple.NavigationServices 3.5.4 (182) <8DC6FD4A-6C74-9C23-A4C3-715B44A8D28C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/NavigationServices.framework/Versions/A/NavigationServices
0x987b6000 - 0x98ad6ff3  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore 861.39 (861.39) <5C59805C-AF39-9010-B8B5-D673C9C38538> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
0x98ad7000 - 0x98b0aff7  com.apple.AE 496.5 (496.5) <BF9673D5-2419-7120-26A3-83D264C75222> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
0x98e48000 - 0x98e4cff7  libGIF.dylib ??? (???) <2251F789-B187-0837-6E38-A0E5C7C4FA3C> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib
0x98e4d000 - 0x98f2dfe7  com.apple.vImage 4.1 (4.1) <D029C515-08E1-93A6-3705-DD062A3A672C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
0x98f2e000 - 0x98f31ffb  com.apple.help 1.3.2 (41.1) <8AC20B01-4A3B-94BA-D8AF-E39034B97D8C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Help.framework/Versions/A/Help
0x99115000 - 0x9911fffb  com.apple.speech.recognition.framework 3.11.1 (3.11.1) <7486003F-8FDB-BD6C-CB34-DE45315BD82C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechRecognition.framework/Versions/A/SpeechRecognition
0x99120000 - 0x99140fe7  libresolv.9.dylib 41.1.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <8C2B5FA8-2469-21C7-D297-F95A0FFE5F19> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x99141000 - 0x99143ff7  libRadiance.dylib ??? (???) <090420B3-CB65-9F7B-5349-D42F2F9693B6> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRadiance.dylib
0x99144000 - 0x993b5fef  com.apple.Foundation 6.6.8 (751.63) <69B3441C-B196-F2AD-07F8-D8DD24E4CD8C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
0x99411000 - 0x9947bfe7  libstdc++.6.dylib 7.9.0 (compatibility 7.0.0) <411D87F4-B7E1-44EB-F201-F8B4F9227213> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x994be000 - 0x994dafe3  com.apple.openscripting 1.3.1 (???) <2A748037-D1C0-6D47-2C4A-0562AF799AC9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OpenScripting.framework/Versions/A/OpenScripting
0x994e5000 - 0x9957dfe7  edu.mit.Kerberos 6.5.11 (6.5.11) <F36DB665-A88B-7F5B-6244-6A2E7FFFF668> /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos
0x99635000 - 0x99636ff7  com.apple.audio.units.AudioUnit 1.6.7 (1.6.7) <93EC71F1-4D4E-F456-8EFE-32E7EFD7A064> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit
0x99866000 - 0x99c7cff7  libBLAS.dylib 219.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <C4FB303A-DB4D-F9E8-181C-129585E59603> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
0x99d2b000 - 0x99d7bff7  com.apple.framework.familycontrols 2.0.2 (2020) <596ADD85-79F5-A613-537B-F83B6E19013C> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyControls.framework/Versions/A/FamilyControls
0x99e2e000 - 0x99e3cff7  com.apple.opengl 1.6.14 (1.6.14) <82622F67-E032-0BF6-A78D-50B346E8D0FD> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
0x99e73000 - 0x99e79fe7  com.apple.CommerceCore 1.0 (9.1) <521D067B-3BDA-D04E-E1FA-CFA526C87EB5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommerceCore.framework/Versions/A/CommerceCore
0x9a272000 - 0x9a32bfe7  libsqlite3.dylib 9.6.0 (compatibility 9.0.0) <52438E77-55D1-C231-1936-76F1369518E4> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x9a48c000 - 0x9a4e9ff7  com.apple.framework.IOKit 2.0 (???) <3DABAB9C-4949-F441-B077-0498F8E47A35> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x9a4ea000 - 0x9a50bfe7  com.apple.opencl 12.3.6 (12.3.6) <B4104B80-1CB3-191C-AFD3-697843C6BCFF> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL
0x9a50c000 - 0x9a50cff7  com.apple.vecLib 3.6 (vecLib 3.6) <FF4DC8B6-0AB0-DEE8-ADA8-7B57645A1F36> /System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
0x9a50d000 - 0x9a831fef  com.apple.HIToolbox 1.6.5 (???) <21164164-41CE-61DE-C567-32E89755CB34> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
0x9a834000 - 0x9a8e2ff3  com.apple.ink.framework 1.3.3 (107) <233A981E-A2F9-56FB-8BDE-C2DEC3F20784> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Versions/A/Ink
0x9a8e3000 - 0x9a8e3ff7  com.apple.Accelerate.vecLib 3.6 (vecLib 3.6) <ABF97DA4-3BDF-6FFD-6239-B023CA1F7974> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
0x9a91e000 - 0x9a9c6ffb  com.apple.QD 3.36 (???) <FA2785A4-BB69-DCB4-3BA3-7C89A82CAB41> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QD.framework/Versions/A/QD
0x9a9c7000 - 0x9a9cbff7  IOSurface ??? (???) <89D859B7-A26A-A5AB-8401-FC1E01AC7A60> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface
0x9a9cc000 - 0x9a9cdff7  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent 1.1 (1) <2D970A9B-77E8-EDC0-BEC6-7580D78B2843> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
0x9aa01000 - 0x9ab0dfe7  libGLProgrammability.dylib ??? (???) <6167CEB0-D8D6-C4D9-DD74-49755ADB540F> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x9ab4f000 - 0x9ac0bfff  com.apple.ColorSync 4.6.8 (4.6.8) <920DD017-8B41-7334-E554-A85DB99EBD5A> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
0xffff0000 - 0xffff1fff  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???) <2DCD13E3-1BD1-6F25-119A-3863A3848B90> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```